# Não consigo criar um repositório remoto e não consigo passar os arquivos do local p/ remoto

Tags: git, github

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: Eu tentei através do github desktop, mas ele passa esse error. Mesmo asssim o nome não foi alterado, não foi deletado e eu tenho acesso a pasta.]

Já tentei através do cmd prompt também. Não deu certo. Eu fui até a pasta com o comando cd /caminho do arquivo. fiz git init, git add, git commit e git remote add origin url. Não deu certo quando dou o git push diz que não acha o repositório.

Me ajude, por favor!

Comment: Qual o formato da url que você usou em `git remote add origin <url>`?

Comment: Vou colocar mais infos acima!

Comment: Quando você usa o comando git remote, o que aparece?

Comment: quando uso git remote aparece escrito apenas origin

Comment: isso significa que seu repositório remoto já está trackeado com o local.
Faça o seguinte : 
git push -u origin master

Comment: fiz isso, mas ele diz depois:                                                   remote: Repository not found. e fatal: repository 'url' not found

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de procurar no seu Github e não existe esse projeto, sendo assim ele realmente não vai conseguir fazer o tracking, você pode então criar um repositorio la com o mesmo nome 'AngularJS' ou fazer o que o Atmos mandou na sua resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rapaz eu acho que o print que você mandou é bem claro. O repositório para o qual você está tentando enviar suas alterações não existe mais, ou foi renomeado, ou você não tem mais permissão para realizar pushs diretamente. Caso o repo exista e você não tenha mais permissão, você vai ter que submeter pull requests. Caso tenha sido renomeado, basta você renomear o remote do seu repositório local para o novo remote do repositório no git (URL do projeto), com o seguinte comando:

`git remote set-url origin novo_remote`